# ¿Como crear sesiones para varios roles?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Quisiera que me apoyen a encontrar una idea u alternativa para el inconveniente que presento. Al iniciar la sesión con el usuario consulta debe abril el archivo consulta.php de la misma forma con el usuario soporte que al loguear me dirija al archivo soporte.php. Espero su apoyo.

-Aquí una captura de como esta formado mi proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

-Aquí una captura de los archivos .php consulta y soporte que están dentro de la carpeta vistas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

-Aqui el codigo en PHP de LOGIN

```
include_once 'conexion.php';
$objeto = new Conexion();
$conexion = $objeto->Conectar();

//recepción de datos enviados mediante POST desde ajax
$usuario = (isset($_POST['usuario'])) ? $_POST['usuario'] : '';
$password = (isset($_POST['password'])) ? $_POST['password'] : '';

$pass = md5($password); //encripto la clave enviada por el usuario para compararla con la clava encriptada y almacenada en la BD

$consulta = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='$usuario' AND password='$pass' ";
$resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
$resultado->execute();

if($resultado->rowCount() >= 1){
    $data = $resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $_SESSION["s_usuario"] = $usuario;
}else{
    $_SESSION["s_usuario"] = null;
    $data=null;
}

print json_encode($data);
$conexion=null;í
```

-Aqui una captura de mis tablas, Mi tabla usuario tiene una llave foranea id_rol

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

-AQUI CODIGO JAVASCRIPT CON AJAX

```
 $('#formLogin').submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var usuario = $.trim($("#usuario").val());    
   var password =$.trim($("#password").val());    

   if(usuario.length == "" || password == ""){
      Swal.fire({
          type:'warning',
          title:'Debe ingresar un usuario y/o password',
      });
      return false; 
    }else{
        $.ajax({
           url:"bd/login.php",
           type:"POST",
           datatype: "json",
           data: {usuario:usuario, password:password}, 
           success:function(data){               
               if(data == "null"){
                   Swal.fire({
                       type:'error',
                       title:'Usuario y/o password incorrecta',
                   });
               }else{
                   Swal.fire({
                       type:'success',
                       title:'¡Conexión exitosa!',
                       confirmButtonColor:'#3085d6',
                       confirmButtonText:'Ingresar'
                   }).then((result) => {
                       if(result.value){
                           window.location.href = "vistas/consulta.php";
                       }
                   })

               }
           }    
        });
    }     
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Perfecto, mira yo usaría lo siguiente:

En tu código login vas a declarar un array:

```
$data    = array();
```

luego vas ingresar los datos del usuario:

tipo así

```
try {
      $stmt     = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='$usuario' AND password='$pass'");
      while($row  = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
      {
         // Assign each row of data to associative array
         $data[] = $row;
      }

      // Return data as JSON
      echo json_encode($data);
   }
   catch(PDOException $e)
   {
      echo $e->getMessage();
   }
```

Para asegurarte vas a imprimir el data en tu petición $ajax

```
console.log(data);
console.log(data.id_rol);
```

y con eso deberías obtener el id del rol y ya allí aplicas el if que necesitas

Comment: Una pregunta, me estas diciendo que cambie mi login por ese codigo o que le añada a mi codigo tu sugerencia ?

Comment: Hola, que agregues a tu código o bien, veo que ya exportas el la linea: $data = $resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); puedes darle el cosole.log de ese data en tu código y poner el resultado

Answer (score 0):

igual en login.php debes agregar

```
if($resultado->rowCount() >= 1){
  $data = $resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($data as $data1) {
    $nombre=$data1['nombre'];
    $foto=$data1['foto'];
    $idrol=$data1['idrol'];
}

$data=$idrol;

$_SESSION["s_usuario"] = $usuario;
$_SESSION["s_nombre"]=$nombre;
$_SESSION["s_foto"]=$foto;

}
```

Comment: rowCount no es la mejor opción, la propia documentación de PHP lo indica https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Comment: o como podria ser otra manera  dentro codigo.js                                                 
             if(result.value){ 
                          if (data==1) {
                            window.location.href = "dashboard/index.php";
                          }
                          else{
                            window.location.href = "dashboard/index1.php";
                          }   
                       }